# How do you change apache to be http 1.0 by default

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd

Is this changed in the httpd.conf? If so, where?

I am having problems with having connections staying alive, and I know http 1.0 makes keep alive off by default.

Comment: You really do not want to even attempt to do this. Your site's performance will suffer horribly, and many things will probably break. [Solve the actual problem instead.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912)

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't try rolling back to apache 1.0 unless you are totally out of options as you may introduce other issues.

If you have not done so already try using these setting first in httpd.conf
(assuming apache2 i.e. redhat based distro | or | apache2.conf if distro=debian based)

```
Timeout 300
MaxKeepAliveRequests 256
KeepAliveTimeout 30
```

if that dosn't work you can also set this directive

```
KeepAlive Off
```

Comment: The (first) configuration above will keep connections alive when the OP's objective seems to be to disable keepalives - and even he wanted to enalbe keepalives - that config is very bad for scalability. And as long as it's greater than the keepalivetimeout, what has timeout got to do with keepalive?